# Combine select with count from two different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, null

I am trying to create a query that will count the amount of different medical specialisms I have worked with.

However, when I add `where specialism=` it does not show the specialisms that have no entry.

Here is the query I have used:

```
SELECT Specialisme, 
   count(Registratie.Specialisme+IIf(IsNull(Specialisme),0,Specialisme)) AS Aantal
FROM Registratie
WHERE (((Registratie.Opleidingsjaar)=1)) 
    AND ((Specialisme='KNO') 
    OR (Specialisme='Mondheelkunde') 
    OR (Specialisme='Oogheelkunde') 
    OR (Specialisme='Neurochirurgie'))
GROUP BY Specialisme;
```

However, I have no entries of `neurochirurgie` or `mondheelkunde`, so it doesn't show these as a row, and I cannot get it to show 'neurochirurgie 0'

I have tried combining the *count query in `Registratie`* with *select specialism query* in the table where I have defined all the different specialisms (where they do have an entry), but then I get all different kinds of error messages

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Could you give us your expect result and sample data?

Comment: Can be closed.
Somehow LEFT JOIN works out now

Answer (score 0):

I think the direction of your solution was right. Here is what I tried and it worked:

```
CREATE TABLE test (Specialisme VARCHAR2(20 CHAR));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('KNO'), ('KNO'), ('Mondheelkunde'), ('Oogheelkunde');
CREATE TABLE all_possible_values (Specialisme VARCHAR2(20 CHAR));
INSERT INTO all_possible_values VALUES ('KNO'), ('Mondheelkunde'),  ('Oogheelkunde'), ('Neurochirurgie');

SELECT y.Specialisme, COUNT(x.Specialisme) 
FROM test x 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN all_possible_values y ON x.Specialisme = y.Specialisme 
GROUP BY Specialisme;
```